# Searching for a database for spaceships, satellites, drones, etc.?

Tags: data-request, transportation

Similar to [this question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/200/database-of-ships) except for space technologies—ships, satellites, drones etc.?

Comment: I saw in an earlier question somebody posted an URL to a website for US drone attacks. I kept the url: http://natsec.newamerica.net/drones/pakistan/analysis

Answer (score 3):

I would guess that scraping lists an timelines linked on the summary page [Spaceflight lists and timeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template%3aSpaceflight_lists_and_timelines) (Wikipedia) will cover most satellites, probes and drones operational today and in the past.

Answer (score 3):

I found this while googling:

*The UCS Satellite Database is a listing of the more than 1000 operational satellites currently in orbit around Earth. Our intent in producing the database is to create a research tool for specialists and non-specialists alike by collecting open-source information on operational satellites and presenting it in a format that can be easily manipulated for research and analysis. It is available as both a downloadable Excel file and in a tab-delimited text format.*

http://www.ucsusa.org/nuclear_weapons_and_global_security/solutions/space-weapons/ucs-satellite-database.html

Answer (score 3):

Nasa have a superb resource at http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/?horizons which covers solar system objects. Satellites and spacecraft as well as asteroids, comets, planets etc

Answer (score 1):

I can't help on the drones -- but NASA has a service called the [Satellite Situation Center](http://sscweb.gsfc.nasa.gov/) that will tell you the location of many spacecraft.  I can only assume that they don't track clasified (ie, secrete military) spacecraft.

Another spacecraft location database is the one at [N2YO](http://www.n2yo.com/).

Unlike aircraft and surface ships, most spacecraft are one-off builds.  There are constellations of spacecraft such as STEREO, CLUSTER, GPS, and Iridium, and there are a few that are built similar for economy of scale (eg, GOES-N, GOES-O, GOES-P), and maybe some communications satellites.

You can get additional information about scientific spacecraft (both current and older) from the [National Space Science Data Center](http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/nmc/SpacecraftQuery.jsp).