# Time of arrival and departure of ships in ports

Tags: transportation, geospatial, trade, oceanographic

Initially asked this question in GIS SE.

Needs to have from port, to port, and time stamps for each (arrival, departure times) and would ideally have route taken in some kind of format I can easily map i.e. geoJSON

Is there a dataset with all of this, or will I need to combine some other ones?

Aware of [Database of ships?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/200), it doesn't give me the info I need.

Comment: Some useful info there, but won't get me the route data I need

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the Climatological Database for the World's Oceans (CLIWOC)? It's built from ship's logs and has the information that you are looking for, albeit from 1750-1850. Should work if you don't need contemporary data.

http://pendientedemigracion.ucm.es/info/cliwoc/cliwoc15.htm

Comment: Thanks, but I need data from at least 2013, ideally 2014