# Maritime traffic data as bulk download or API

Tags: data-request, api, transportation

I am looking for a dataset of global maritime traffic which would include basic metadata such as port of departure/arrival, date, vessel name.

I am familiar with proprietary online services, such as marinetraffic, but would be interested in a free API/bulk download option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Database of ships?](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/200/database-of-ships)

Comment: I am not sure that this is really a duplicate because the other question focusses on ships but not on their movements. So I vote to leave it open as a separate question.

Comment: Did you found any API or soap service?

Answer (score 2):

coast guard will have some/most of this. at least for the US. http://cgmix.uscg.mil/PSIX/Default.aspx

EDIT: this may also be worth picking over:
http://cgmix.uscg.mil/PSIX/AdditionalLinks.aspx

Comment: No bulk download option - it appears?

Comment: not sure...none that are obvious

Comment: you may be able to access more data by requesting access to it...form here -> https://cgmix.uscg.mil/Forms/VISUserrequestform10-Dec-2015.pdf