# Availability of descriptive ship metadata

Tags: data-request, transportation, metadata, database, ais

I'm creating my own ship position map by [AIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_identification_system) (Automatic Identification System) messages from the base transceiver station (BTS).

Can I find a free database of static information about the ships by [MMSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maritime_Mobile_Service_Identity) (Maritime Mobility Service Identity) number ?

I need only ship name, type and dimensions.

Comment: Duplicate of http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/200/1511 ?

Comment: Also, BTS is Bureau of Transportation Statistics, or the [Korean boy band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BTS_(band))?

Comment: Bts means base transceiver station. I understand, that there is no non-commercial database of ships ?

Answer (score 0):

All moving ship use the AIS stream to transmit static data using `ShipStaticData` messages, that show some characteristics of the ship

```
ShipStaticData: {
      AisVersion: 0,
      CallSign: '9V2881 ',
      Destination: 'GR AGT              ',
      Dimension: [Object],
      Dte: false,
      Eta: [Object],
      FixType: 1,
      ImoNumber: 9324306,
      MaximumStaticDraught: 13,
      MessageID: 5,
      Name: 'PM IMPERIAL         ',
      RepeatIndicator: 0,
      Spare: false,
      Type: 89,
      UserID: 564956000,
      Valid: true
    }
```

The `Dimension` property includes some information on the dimensions of the ship. You can try and wait until it sails on the vicinity of some station, and grab that data. Other than that, you can try [VesselFinder](https://vesselfinder.com) which will give you its current position; it's not available via API as far as I can tell.